# I have 2 time in PHP, how can I run a foreach loop to go through all of those days? (1 Hour loop same time Last 24 Hours!)

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, query-builder

I'm starting with a time `now()` and ending with `last 24 Hours`. How can I iterate through all of those times in PHP?

One time each `same time` one and second time `loop` started...

Comment: can you provide  an example, i have read the question multiple times and I'm unsure what you actually want. An attempt to solve this your self would also help

Comment: can you share some code and examples

Comment: one time => 8:00 am  as Second Time => 8:00 am @tim

Comment: Last 24 hours in foreach loop Ex.= 12:00 am to 11:59 pm

Comment: My English is Week So, You Understand... Sorry...

Comment: You can try CarbonPeriod and loop through 2 dates.
Https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period

Comment: Yes, but no idea...

Comment: ok thanks.. I have solution define in laravel ...@krunalpawar

Comment: last 24 hours..@krunalpawar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of the php documentation you will likely need for this project:

- [PHP: Relative Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)
- [PHP: Compound Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php)
- [PHP: strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
- [PHP: strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

Here is *sample* code that will give the last 24 hours in one hour decrements:

```
$timenow = time();
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i ++) {
    $ago = strtotime("$i hours ago",$timenow);
    echo $ago ," <-- ",strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',$ago),"\n";
```

It uses these formats from the relative formats:

> **number space? (unit | 'week')**
>     Handles relative time items where the value is a number.
>     "+5 weeks", "12 day", "-7 weekdays"
>
> **'ago'**
>     Negates all the values of previously found relative time items.
>     "2 days ago", "8 days ago 14:00", "2 months 5 days ago", "2 months
>   ago 5 days", "2 days ago"

Here is sample output:

```
1554384488 <-- 2019-04-04 09:28:08
1554380888 <-- 2019-04-04 08:28:08
1554377288 <-- 2019-04-04 07:28:08
1554373688 <-- 2019-04-04 06:28:08
1554370088 <-- 2019-04-04 05:28:08
1554366488 <-- 2019-04-04 04:28:08
1554362888 <-- 2019-04-04 03:28:08
1554359288 <-- 2019-04-04 02:28:08
1554355688 <-- 2019-04-04 01:28:08
1554352088 <-- 2019-04-04 00:28:08
1554348488 <-- 2019-04-03 23:28:08
1554344888 <-- 2019-04-03 22:28:08
1554341288 <-- 2019-04-03 21:28:08
1554337688 <-- 2019-04-03 20:28:08
1554334088 <-- 2019-04-03 19:28:08
1554330488 <-- 2019-04-03 18:28:08
1554326888 <-- 2019-04-03 17:28:08
1554323288 <-- 2019-04-03 16:28:08
1554319688 <-- 2019-04-03 15:28:08
1554316088 <-- 2019-04-03 14:28:08
1554312488 <-- 2019-04-03 13:28:08
1554308888 <-- 2019-04-03 12:28:08
1554305288 <-- 2019-04-03 11:28:08
1554301688 <-- 2019-04-03 10:28:08
```